# Querying NCBI for a sequence from ncbi via Biopython

Tags: sequence, bioinformatics, biopython, ncbi

How can I query NCBI for sequences given a chromosome's Genbank identifier, and start and stop positions using Biopython?

```
CP001665    NAPP    TILE    6373    6422    .   +   .   cluster=9; 
CP001665    NAPP    TILE    6398    6447    .   +   .   cluster=3; 
CP001665    NAPP    TILE    6423    6472    .   +   .   cluster=3; 
CP001665    NAPP    TILE    6448    6497    .   +   .   cluster=3;
CP001665    NAPP    TILE    7036    7085    .   +   .   cluster=10; 
CP001665    NAPP    TILE    7061    7110    .   +   .   cluster=3; 
CP001665    NAPP    TILE    7073    7122    .   +   .   cluster=3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO

Entrez.email = "sample@example.org"

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore",
                       id="CP001665",
                       rettype="gb",
                       retmode="text")

whole_sequence = SeqIO.read(handle, "genbank")

print whole_sequence[6373:6422]
```

Once you know the `id` and the database to fetch from, use `Entrez.efetch` to get a handle to that file. You should specify the returning type (`rettype="gb"`) and the mode (`retmode="text"`), to get a handler to the filelike data.

Then pass this handler to `SeqIO`, which should return a `SeqRecord` object. One nice feature of the `SeqRecord`s is that they can be cleanly sliced as lists. If you can retrieve the starting and ending points from somewhere, the above `print` statement returns:

```
ID: CP001665.1
Name: CP001665
Description: Escherichia coli 'BL21-Gold(DE3)pLysS AG', complete genome.
Number of features: 0
Seq('GCGCTAACCATGCGAGCGTGCCTGATGCGCTACGCTTATCAGGCCTACG', IUPACAmbiguousDNA())
```

Comment: @user3744999 As a side comment, don't abuse the efetch: NCBI might throttle down or ban you. If you have a lot of lines with the same id, efetch it only once and then use the same SeqRecord for every other line with that id.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something similar to this?

```
    from Bio import Entrez
    Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="genome", id="56", rettype="fasta")
```

You'll need to determine the right database and query for it. I'd suggest using the Assembly Advanced Search Builder to build your query and see if you can go around the problem that way:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/advanced

Answer (score 0):

To download Nucleotide/Protein sequences it is not necessary to use Biopython.You can use urllib2 instead or Biopython or Bioperl.Here List contaiins NCBI GI IDs.

```
import urllib2
List = ['440906003','440909279','440901052']
for gi in List:
    url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.cgi?    tool=portal&sendto=on&log$=seqview&db=protein&dopt=fasta&sort=&val='+gi+'&from=begin&to=end&maxplex=1'
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    page = resp.read()
    print (page),
```